# Firefox Cross-Site Access Error for Fonts

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face, cdn

We just started using Amazon Cloudfront's CDN to load our files and we are having trouble getting the @font-face fonts to load in Firefox.  Per some recommendations, we added the following code to our htaccess file, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

The fonts do show up sometimes, but we still see errors in the console for each font.  You can check it out at http://wiredimpact.com.

Also, the main WordPress post I used to learn about this is http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-font-face-not-working-in-firefox?replies=21.

Any suggestions on how to get the fonts to load in Firefox correctly?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I adjusted the code used in htaccess to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*.wiredimpact.com"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This not only adds the font.css file, which seems to help in Firefox, but it also only loads from our subdomains, which is better for security purposes.  The fonts seem to be loading now in Firefox, but the errors are still showing up in the console.

Comment: Is the issue intermittent?  I'm using Firefox v 14.0.1 and I don't see the issue.  No errors in the web console or in firebug...

Comment: It is intermittent.  I'm wondering if this is a caching issue on my end.  Is there a way to do a hard refresh in Firefox where the page loads completely?

Comment: Control + F5 will force a complete reload in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @Cypher.  I did that and the fonts still don't load for me.  I'm using Firefox v14.0.1.

Comment: I've done numerous force-reloads of http://wiredimpact.com and all the fonts are successfully downloading from cdn2.wiredimpact.com. Can you post some of the errors that you are seeing?

Comment: Just to be clear, I see a number of css *warnings*, but no *errors* (be it css, network, or otherwise).

Comment: The errors I'm seeing all look like: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "OpenSans" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://cdn2.wiredimpact.com/wp-content/themes/wiredimpact/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff
http://cdn2.wiredimpact.com/wp-content/themes/wiredimpact/fonts/fonts.css
Line 0

Comment: I'm also only looking at errors, not the warnings.  Thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: Try setting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` on whatever webserver is hosting cdn2.wiredimpact.com.  (I'm assuming you're .htaccess snippet above is for your webserver hosting the page, not the fonts).

Comment: I wish I could do that, but unfortunately, that is a CNAME that points to Amazon's CloudFront CDN.  I don't have any control over their HTTP headers.

Comment: Bummer.  I think that error may be coming from their server, not yours, since the error "source" is being identified as cdn2.wiredimpact.com, and not wiredimpact.com.

Comment: Still odd that errors are thrown but yet... the fonts still download and display... o.O

Comment: Yeah, very weird.  I'm hoping it's just a caching issue.  So you're seeing all the fonts and getting no errors at all, even on a hard refresh?

Comment: Actually after I went into Firefox's settings and cleared the browser cache, the next force refresh I did displayed the errors.  However, the fonts seemed to have downloaded even with the errors.  Firebug is showing me OpenSans, CodePro, Serif12Beta... mind you - it only happened **once**. Next force refresh... no errors. Wonder if there's an Amazon CDN server out there that is configured differently and when we try to download from it that's when we're getting the errors?  Just a guess..

Comment: It's definitely possible that not all of their servers have been updated and that's causing the issue.  We need someone with a far better understanding of CloudFront than me to help us out.  Thanks for all the work @Cypher.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: From a different computer using Firefox the errors didn't show up, but the fonts also didn't load entirely.  @Cypher, when the errors don't show is the font loading?  Is the navigation loaded using CodeProDemo or Tahoma?  If they're loading correctly the navigation should use CodeProDemo.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes.  The fonts seem to always load whether or not errors are spat out in the console.  I see CodeProDemo, Serif12Beta, OpenSans, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I might have to remove the font files from the cdn.  I can't find a solution and the Access-Control-Origin solution doesn't appear to work on all Firefox browsers.

Comment: For anyone else who is looking into this, I never did find a solution and had to adjust W3 Total Cache in WordPress to load the font files from the original wiredimpact.com domain name.  I did this by adding `wp-content/themes/wiredimpact/fonts/fonts.css` under the rejected files section of the CDN settings.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [icoMoon fonts doesn't show-up on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666722/icomoon-fonts-doesnt-show-up-on-firefox#8203;icomoon-fonts-doesn) by @meaganoff:

> I was having issues with icomoon and Firefox as well. Have you tried
>   [Paul Irish's 'bulletproof' `@font-face` syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)? It's a little
>   different than what icomoon outputs and I've had better luck with it -
>   no FF issues since.
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>     font-family: 'Graublau Web';
>     src: url('GraublauWeb.eot?') format('eot'), url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('GraublauWeb.ttf')
> ```
>
> format('truetype');
>       }

And worked like a charm!